# How can I pass a 'unicode string' to os.environ within a wsgi.py

Tags: apache, environment-variables, mod-wsgi, python-3.5, django-wsgi

- apache2
- wsgi
- VHOST
- python3

If I try to set envvars as part of my wsgi.py I do run into problems if values contain non-ascii characters.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vagrant/pyvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/absys/config/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
os.environ['DJANGO_TESTVAR'] = 'M\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb6'
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 730, in __setitem__
value = self.encodevalue(value)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 799, in encode
return value.encode(encoding, 'surrogateescape')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I try to do the same thing as a regular user or as root it works flawlessly. This seems to be due to the fact that `os.environ` does accept the passed unicode value ('Müüü') and does *not* try to encode it.
For a reason not understood the same does not seem to be true when run as part of `wsgi.py`

For a second I thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703451/apache-ldap-and-wsgi-encoding-issue#31737278) could provide an answer but setting `LANG = de_DE.UTF-8`in `/etc/apache2/envvars` did not change a thing.

I tried to read pretty much most of the resources around on django/wsgi/envvars and in particular [Graham Dumpletons approach](https://gist.github.com/GrahamDumpleton/b380652b768e81a7f60c) 
but none of them seem to mention any encoding issues.

I guess, my question (governed by my understanding so far) boils down to:
"What governs `os.environ`s encoding behaviour and how to influence it within the wsgi process?

If there is any additional information I can provide to aid finding an answer please let me know.

Comment: Some Linux systems ignore the ``envvars`` file. Ensure you are using daemon mode of mod_wsgi and use the ``lang/locale`` options of ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` directive. See: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/setting-lang-and-lcall-when-using.html and http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is just a reiteration of Graham Dumpleton's most helpfull comment. All credit is his.*

This problem most likely is the result of messed up `locale` setting in the wsgi-processes environment.

In case your `mod_wsgi` is run as its own dedicated deamon (as it most likely should) you can pass it the desired locale directly and hence avoid any issues due to how your distribution may handle apaches environment.

For this something along these lines should do the trick:
`WSGIDaemonProcess my-django-site lang='en_US.UTF-8' locale='en_US.UTF-8'`.

For a more elaborate explaination please read Grahams [excellent blog post](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/setting-lang-and-lcall-when-using.html) and refer to `mod_wsgi`'s [documentation](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html).